# javascript : setting values in a function that will be evaluated later

Tags: javascript, function, eval

Sorry, I am not really sure how to describe this issue, which probably made me fail to find an answer as well.

But from my code the issue should be understandable.

First thing first : the code works, but I don' t like the workaround I implemented, so I was wondering if you guys know a better way to achieve the same thing.

I created a sort of helper function to handle rollups in d3js :

```
function puD3Rollup(data,keys,rollups)
{
  var nested_data = d3.nest();
  for (var k=0;k<keys.length;k++)
  nested_data= eval("nested_data.key(function(d) { return  d["+keys[k]+"];});");
  nested_data= nested_data.rollup(function(leaves) 
  { 
   var ret = {};
   for (var i=0;i<rollups.length;i++)
   {
     if (rollups[i].rollup==__stem.count) ret[rollups[i].name]= leaves.length;
     if (rollups[i].rollup==__stem.sum) ret[rollups[i].name]= d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {return parseFloat(d[rollups.column]);});
     if (rollups[i].rollup==__stem.avg) ret[rollups[i].name]= d3.mean(leaves, function(d) {return parseFloat(d[rollups.column]);});
     if (rollups[i].rollup==__stem.min) ret[rollups[i].name]= d3.min(leaves, function(d) {return parseFloat(d[rollups.column]);});
     if (rollups[i].rollup==__stem.max) ret[rollups[i].name]= d3.max(leaves, function(d) {return parseFloat(d[rollups.column]);});
 }    
 return ret;
 });
 return nested_data.entries(data);  
}
```

...and I call this function like this (just an example)

```
puD3Rollup(__team.data,[1],[{rollup:__stem.count,column:3,name:"pscount"}])
```

this takes :
-a data array (__team.data)
 
-specifies that I want to group by column at position 1
 
-finally defines as output a single column which is a rollup (count) of the input column 3, with label "pscount".

The issue is with the eval part (which I don' t like).
Normally I would have

```
nested_data= nested_data.key(function(d) { return  d[keys[k]];});
```

BUT since I am defining a function that will be evaluated later, it wont be able to get the correct value of k and therefore of keys[k].
Obviously evaluating the function as a text and thus making keys[k] a constant, works.

But is there a cleaner way to achieve this?
I have the feeling there must be a trivial solution I am missing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest method here (assuming IE9 or later, or other browsers) is to replace your `for` loop with a `.forEach` call:

```
keys.forEach(function(k) {
    nested_data = nested_data.key(function(d) {
        return d[k];
    });
    ...
})
```

The parameter `k` to the callback is now "bound" in the scope of the inner `.key` callback, and will hold the correct value when it's invoked.

Comment: Yeah! I knew it was something trivial I did nto notice :) Sure, your solution works perfectly. For some dumb reason I tend to be "alergic" to forEach loops, but the scope thing is indeed a good reason to consider them more often (I always regarded them as a mere syntax alternative... whcih they are not, as you just demonstrated). Thanks!

Comment: @saburo in ES6 you can use `let` instead of `var` to get a block scoped variable that would also act "correctly".

Comment: Thanks, luckily this code should work for an "internal" application, where we can assume users have IE9+ (normally Safari, Chrome or IE11).

Comment: @saburo it can be shimmed trivially for older browsers if required.  D3 doesn't work on anything prior to IE9 anyway.